# Can I delete Xcode?

Tags: xcode, homebrew, php

I'm a php developer, usually with the laravel framework. I want to get rid of Xcode because I'm tired of dedicating 9 gigabytes of storage to an application that I don't use at all.

I seem to remember that when setting up git, homebrew, or ssh, that one of these applications has dependencies which are contained inside of Xcode.

Can I delete Xcode? What will doing so break? How can I delete Xcode gracefully?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can, as long as you install the command line tools.

You can then install the command line tools with `xcode-select --install`

For more information (from the iOS Dev Library, but applicable in this case), see [Technical Note TN2339](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-DOWNLOADING_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS_IS_NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_XCODE_FOR_OS_X_10_9__HOW_CAN_I_INSTALL_THEM_ON_MY_MACHINE_)

Comment: After running this, I also had to run `sudo xcode-select --reset` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009531/xcrun-error-active-developer-path-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer).